# Can't install libpcre3-dev on Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Tags: apt

I'm trying

```
apt install libpcre3-dev
```

I get

```
eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcre3-dev : Depends: libpcre3 (= 2:8.39-12build1) but 
 2:8.43-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install libpcre3:

```
apt install libpcre3
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libpcre3 is already the newest version (2:8.43-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1).
```

How can I solve this issue?
Note, I need to install libpcre3-dev because I want to build Nginx from source, where I get:

> ./configure: error: the HTTP rewrite module requires the PCRE library.
> You can either disable the module by using --without-http_rewrite_module
> option, or install the PCRE library into the system, or build the PCRE library
> statically from the source with nginx by using --with-pcre= option.

As per request here is the output of `apt-cache policy libpcre3 libpcre3-dev`

```
libpcre3:
  Installed: 2:8.43-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 2:8.43-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
 *** 2:8.43-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:8.39-12build1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libpcre3-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:8.39-12build1
  Version table:
     2:8.39-12build1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libpcre3 libpcre3-dev` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert Done..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to install packages with versions specified:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3=2:8.39-12build1 libpcre3-dev=2:8.39-12build1
```

This happened because of the following: some time ago you have installed `libpcre3` from PPA, but the PPA is now removed or disabled.

Comment: I love you <3 <3

Comment: @AymaneShuichi Please mark N0rbert's answer as correct if it solved your problem!

Comment: I need to wait 2 minutes, I'm trying.. ok?

Comment: It should work for sure.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev` didn't work. But indeed it was a ppa issue like @N0rbert said (thanks). Therefore I did  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and `sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev` works (without versions). For informationI got this error after `sudo apt install r-base-dev`.